# How to access JSON in '(String, JSON)'

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to get the value in a '(String, JSON)'

When printed the whole SwiftyJSON object looks like:

```
("0", {
  "created_at" : "2016-05-01T14:39:10.000Z",
  "user_id" : 2,
  "id" : 75,
  "item_id" : 172,
  "updated_at" : "2016-05-01T14:39:10.000Z"
})
```

Assume the object is called: jstring_info

I would like to do this:

```
let item_id = jstring_info[1]["item_id"]
```

so that `print(item_id)` would give 172

But this is not the proper syntax, and I cannot find it anywhere online.

The error that the above code gives is `Type 'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') has no subscript members`

Comment: You sure that it's a JSON? I don't think so.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese it's a SwiftyJSON object

Comment: It's Tuple, so you can access it easily by typing out the instance, the Xcode will autocomplete the inside objects for you. And by getting that JSON, value you can access the key "item_id". Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Tuple, So that you access it like this.

```
   let itemId = jstring_info.1["item_id"]
```

Just start typing the instance in you code, Xcode will autocomplete the objects inside the tuple, after selecting your `JSON` object you can access the key inside it.

These example will help you a bit.

```
        let person : (String,Int) = ("alvin", 789)
        person.0 // represents String alvin
        person.1 // represents Integer 789
```

And this,

```
        let person : (name : String,age : Int) = ("alvin", 789)
        person.name // represents name alvin
        person.age // represents age 789
```